# How to use mail template in windows console, using C#?

Tags: c#, console, sendmail

I have created a windows console application, and I have to send an email. I want to create a mail template and replace some value in mail template.

I have created a mail template (/MailTemplate/Resignnotify.html).

How to use mail template as below in windows console application ?

my Resignnotify.html,

```
   <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    Hi ! ##User## 
                </td>
            </tr>
            
            
            <tr>
                <td>Company：</td>
                <td>##AppCom##</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>People：</td>
                <td>##AppUser##</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Date: </td>
                <td>##ResignDate## </td>
            </tr>
        
        </table>
```

Comment: It looks like you've solved it. What is the problem?

Comment: @PalleDue no ,I am not yet solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Create a class for values for replacing markers in the HTML file.

```
public class TemplateItem
{
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string AppCom { get; set; }
    public List<string> AppUser { get; set; }
    public DateTime ResignDate { get; set; }
}
```

Create a class for performing marker/token replacements.

```
public class TemplateOperations
{
    public static string Populate(string fileName, TemplateItem templateItem)
    {
        string contents = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
        
        contents = contents.Replace("##User##", templateItem.User);
        contents = contents.Replace("##AppCom##", templateItem.AppCom);
        contents = contents.Replace("##AppUser##", string.Join(",", templateItem.AppUser));
        contents = contents.Replace("##ResignDate##", templateItem.ResignDate.ToString("d"));

        return contents;

    }
}
```

Run above in Main method

```
partial class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TemplateItem templateItem = new TemplateItem
        {
            AppCom = "ABC",
            AppUser = new List<string>() { "Mike", "Jane", "Fran" },
            ResignDate = DateTime.Now,
            User = "Adam"
        };

        string fileName = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, 
            "MailTemplate", "Resignnotify.html");

        var body = TemplateOperations.Populate(fileName, templateItem);

        Console.WriteLine(body);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

[image]